# Intellij isn't breaking on uncaught exceptions

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, clojure

I'm getting a NullPointerException while writing Clojure in Intellij. When trying to debug it, Intellij is refusing to break when the exception happens.

Here's a screenshot that sums up the situation:

[image]

Note in the breakpoint manager on the left, I have a breakpoint set for `NullPointerException`s to fire when an uncaught exception happens. On the right, you can see that despite this breakpoint being set, a NPE is still managing to get through. I know from the rest of the message I seem to be trying to cast a `null`/`nil` to a double, but without a stack trace that's only so helpful.

If I check "Caught exception" it fires, but then I have to sift through a ton of NPE's that are happening internally that don't have anything to do with my problem. If I make it more general and ask it to break on any uncaught exception, it still refuses to break.

I don't think including code is necessary since I don't expect anyone to actually debug it for me; I'm more curious as to why it's not breaking when I expect it to.

Comment: A good reason to  check for `null` instead of catching NullPointerExceptions. Throwing exceptions is also time consuming.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm not sure what you mean. You mean in the code check for null? Null should never be in the function. It's not being passed in, so it must be that I'm not accounting for an empty list or something somewhere. I just wrote the function, and this happened on the first test.